# Sorting data from excel spreadsheets into new files

Tags: excel, csv

so my issue comes from the excel data I currently have which I need to convert into 4 separate forms, each with different details. The specfics don't really matter, but what I'm trying to do is code some kind of script that would do into this data and extract the stuff I need, therefore saving me tons of time copying and pasting.

The problem is, i'm not really sure where to start. I have done some research so I am familiar with csv files and I already have a pretty good grasp on java. What would be the best way to approach this problem, from what I have researched, python is very helpful at these string type manipulations, but I also know that it could be done in java using buffered reads/file writes, but I feel like that could get really clunky.

Thanks

Comment: What format are you looking to convert into - 4 new Excel workbooks? Presumably VBA is the way forward - hit Alt + F11 in Excel and it will pop up and let you do your magic

Comment: I have them as xlsx right now, so it would all be inside excel

Comment: Great, can you give us an idea of what you actually want to happen? (eg move all of sheet1 into excel workbook B, move any data currently in bold into workbookC, etc etc?)

Comment: Ideally I would like to have a script run on my rawdata.xls file, then go through down the cells, and send the data from the cell to 1 of the 4 forms it belongs in. They could all be in the same workbook

Comment: OK, and what is the criteria, as in, how do you know which of the four forms it should go to? And where are the four forms - each on their own sheet?